# Annoying Safari pop up when I click show password in preferences and no favicon support

Tags: macos, mac, safari, keychain

An hour ago I decided to switch to Safari 6.0 on Mac OSX 10.7.4 from Google Chrome and here I am with two issues.

```
Issue 1:
```

Visiting preferences I eventually went to **Password Tab** as shown in screenshot below. As I checked **show password** option all of a sudden this pop up asking for permission : **"safari wants to use your confidential information stored in your keychain."**

As I have about 100 websites passwords stored in my keychain, this pop up keeps coming one by one asking for permission for each and every site. And until I select any of 3 options I can not do any activity. I do not want to click 100 times on **Always Allow** option. This behavior is completely nuisance to me. Any suggestion on how to get rid of this? Is this a bug in Safari? Should I report it to Apple?[image]

```
  Issue 2:
```

I figured out that Safari does not support favicons too, which is, in my opinion very efficient way to manage bookmark on Bookmark bar as bookmarks are easily searchable. I visited few questions regarding Favicons and all says NO support for Safari but since they are quite a few months older now I am including it here, with hope, if any solution is known to anyone.
Any suggestion or assistance will be helpful for any of the issue.

*Due to these two issues I am forced to switch back to chrome within an hour. :-(*

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1: This is not a bug, but a security feature. Safari should require you to confirm that you want your password and user info stored securely for each and every site.

Issue 2: I do not think Safari has addons that allow favicons in bookmarks. While Safari is a good browser, I think Google Chrome is far superior. Plus with the integration of google accounts, you don't have to continually accept password keychain requests if you switch between personal and work computers or what-have-you.

Comment: Can't they have option/checkbox like: **"Remember this for all sites"/ "DO NOT ASK ME AGAIN"?**

Comment: Also there is no way to synch your bookmarks currently in Safari like we have in Chrome, right?

Comment: Bug or Feature... whatever you call it, it's a HORRIBLE user experience. And as I've seen the SAME domain pop up multiple times after clicking "Always Allow" it's one of the buggiest feeling "feature"s I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

I'll address only the *Issue 1*, which is the title of this question. <sup><sub>IMO, *Issue 2* should be a different question.</sub></sup>

I'm not exactly sure what goes on but, as I found on the blog article [*How to stop Google Chrome’s annoying keychain access request messages*](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/03/04/google-chrome-wants-to-use-your-confidential-information-store-in-the-keychain/), it has something to do with using two browsers (Chrome and Safari, can't tell about other combinations), having a password manager (LastPass, 1Password) and the password being stored as `Web form password` in Keychain Access.

I was having the issue with a specific site, say `http://example.com`, and my solution was to remove all passwords stored on the Keychain and let the password manager handle everything.

A definitive answer would need an in-depth troubleshooting.